# Do CS:GO competitive teams consist of the players of different skill levels?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, competitive-gaming

When playing competitive mode, does CS:GO create teams consisting of different skill levels? For example, can a Gold Nova player be in the same group as Silver 1? While playing, it seems to me that there is a pretty huge gap between some players, but I am not sure if it is due to smurfing, large gap inside the skill level, or them actually being from different skill levels.

Comment: A side question: if the different skill levels in the same team is a possibility, then how large can the gap be? For example, can a Legendary Eagle be in the same team as a Silver 1 player?

Answer (score 1):

Games like CS:GO that used matchmaking are always hoping to balance skill levels with wait time; if the player is waiting too long for a match, they're likely not to play, or have a bad experience.

Each game's algorithm is kind of "secret sauce" and it's unclear how they weigh different things. For instance, a player who's on the upswing in terms of performance can be matched against higher-skilled players - where Valve thinks they might end up eventually. In Dota, I know there's a lot of problems with skill matching at higher levels because of the variance between skill levels.

I think this is what drives the interest for FACEIT usage outside of CS:GO; the variance can be a difference between feeling totally outclassed and discouraged as a player.

I would imagine that Valve's secret sauce for CS:GO factors in trying to get the closest grouping of players together with a minimum amount of wait time, but also factoring in ping/geographical location.